# jasig CAS hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate-mapping, cas

I configured the JpaServiceRegistryDaoImpl like it's documented [here](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Service-Management.html#considerations) to store the services in the database.

Now the cas is generating some Table:

- locks
- RegisteredServiceImpl
- rs_attributes
- TICKETGRANTINGTICKET

Why are these Tables are generated? 
And how can I change the table names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the table names. the schema is automatically created for you so CAS can store services. You can mod the CAS configuration to disable schema generation, but the names have to be there.